# Can we have a faster way of creating an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, series

Is there a faster way to create the following array? I need to create an array for further calculation.
This array creation is taking lot of time to run. Basically I need to create a Series or an array with values of norm.ppf function of size 4000.

```
 nrow = 4000
 lts = pandas.Series(numpy.zeros(nrow))
 lts = lts.apply(lambda x : norm.ppf(random.random(),10),5))
 lts = np.asarray(lts, int)
```

Comment: What is the `5` meant to be doing?  Is `x` meant to be used for something?

Comment: In norm.ppf(probability, mean, standard deviation) so 10 is mean and 5 is std. My code will apply the norm.ppf for every element of lts.

Comment: But your parentheses are misplaced, so your code isn't syntactically valid, and `5` isn't an argument to `norm.ppf`.  (See the `)` after the 10.)

Answer (score 6):

You're not using Pandas for any purpose other than Series being a container, so it will be faster to cut Pandas out of this calculation.

Presumably, `norm` is `scipy.stats.norm`. If so, `norm.ppf`'s first argument can be a numpy array. So it will be a whole lot quicker to call `norm.ppf` *once* on an NumPy array of size 4000 than to call `norm.ppf` 4000 times on floats:

```
lts = norm.ppf(np.random.random(4000), 10, 5).astype('int')
```

---

```
In [120]: %timeit lts = norm.ppf(np.random.random(4000), 10, 5).astype('int')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.51 ms per loop

In [121]: %%timeit
   .....: lts_orig = pd.Series(np.zeros(nrow))
   .....: lts_orig = lts_orig.apply(lambda x : norm.ppf(random.random(),10, 5))
   .....: lts_orig = np.asarray(lts_orig, int)
   .....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 572 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @unutbu. Explanation for people who didn't get, lts = norm.ppf(np.random.random(4000), 10,5).astype('int') will create 4000 random variable and calculate norm.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.